# Main Menu to Display Quicktabs Block?

Tags: views, routes, blocks

I am using D7.4.

I have a vocabulary named 'recipes'. I want a tab/link in the Main Menu to take me to the Recipes category.

I also have a block of QuickTabs setup. Inside this block are individual views for: most recent, most viewed, most comments, most votes- all using the 'recipes' vocabulary as the input.

So when a user clicks on the Recipes Link/Tab on the main menu- they'll be presented with 4 choices- most recent/viewed/commented/voted.

I have the quicktabs portion working correctly. How do I get it to display off of a link from the Main Menu?  Do I have to create a separate Node, and declare that specific QuickTabs Block to ONLY show on that specific node, then link that node to the main menu?  Or, is there a better way via views?

It seems soo simple - just can't figure this out.